# Ipv6 6to4 with DMZ

Tags: router, home-networking, ipv6

My question is very simple. I can obtain a 6to4 IPv6 tunnel that I want to use for experimenting and developing on IPv6 networks.

My ONT (home gateway) has theoretically no support for IPv6. I say theoretically because I have not enough info (check for Huawei HG8245Q and correct me if I am wrong).

Anyway my ISP provides no IPv6. I have a router that I want to use behind my ONT in DMZ mode.

**Question is**: does the DMZ allow forwarding 6to4 packets?

I am trying to answer my own question, and the answer could be: it depends.

Basically when talking about NATs, a DMZ can be forwarded all the traffic that the main entry router can't handle. This definition includes 6to4 packets.

On the contrary, home networking devices normally work on the TCP/IP stack only. I wouldn't be surprised if a home router's firmware implementation treats the DMZ only as a special port forwarding rule, thus not supporting level-4 IPv6 packets. On the contrary of contrary, another vendor **may** implement a DMZ in the firewall so that "unhandled traffic goes forwarded to DMZ host".

Actual hardware is: Huawei HG8245Q and TP-Link Archer D7 or C7

Comment: If you buy a network device made in the last 15 or so years it probably supports IP6. Yours uses the phrase, 'IPv6/IPv4 dual stack, and DS-Lite' in the [flyer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjSrenmkJDUAhXpz4MKHc8CDwgQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvectorsolutions.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F02%2F170220-huawei-hg8245q-kk.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEB2R_43L872n9Kfk9yq8Bk-uXu3Q&sig2=SOZFKqQlY4XDhl7X6Rw4jg&cad=rja). That means it works with either or both addressing methods.

Comment: I think that my ISP locked the Ipv6 stack out of the firmware. The device should namely support static routes as an example, but I can't modify them in the control panel. I have no Ipv6 setting anyway

Comment: Complain to your ISP. They should offer IPv6 these days. 6to4 is not a solution because it is too unreliable. A 6in4 tunnel to i.e. Hurricane Electric may be a workable temporary solution.

Comment: My ISP doesn't offer IPv6 by contract. In my country, TLC regulations do not yet require IPv6 as minimum standard. Our regulator thinks that as soon as you can post selfies on Instagram and see legally-streamed videos on Netflix everything is good. If I try to phone them to complain I could either get answer "We don't know what IPv6 is. Is it on the contract? No? Sorry, can't help" or "[ISP Name] is working with technology partners to adopt IPv6 and deploy it to the customer base. We will keep our customers informed of progress". Hurricane Electric **is** my temporary solution

Comment: My last ISP provided IPv6 but while I had my computer assigned an IPv6 address, I couldn't traceroute to Google or anything. I gave up. I am trying now because I just changed